# T-SQL find strings with lone line feed character (missing a carriage return)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been looking around and I've found similar questions, but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

There's some input error or other that happens where there are tables that end up with a lone line feed character -- CHAR(10) with no carriage return before it -- CHAR(13), which is the proper format. I've parsed through the rows and found that some have CR/LF and/or an orphaned LF.

How can I find strings that contain **both** a CR/LF and the orphaned LF character?

This the code I have so far

```
SELECT 
    example.ID
    , example.DESCRIPTION
    WHERE 
    example.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
    AND example.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

which finds strings containing *only* lone LF chars, not **both**.

I've also tried variations of

```
DESCRIPTION LIKE '%[^CHAR(13)][CHAR(10)]%'
```

without any luck. Help?

EDIT: If unclear, the correct format is CR/LF or *CHAR*(13)*CHAR*(10).

Comment: what happens in string with both? is the lone LF anywhere in the string (say "description")? or at the end , something like they end as CRLFLF? or do you mean some rows where "description" has only LF and some other rows where "description" ends with CRLF within the same table?

Comment: Jayvee has a good question as the right(DESCRIPTION, 2) would narrow it down to the description ending if so.  Are you ultimately trying to replace them?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The lone LF is anywhere in the the description string. I'm not focused on the string ending so much as finding the lone LF wherever it's located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  Use `PATINDEX` for slightly more complicated string matches than LIKE:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (S varchar(100))
DECLARE @PAT varchar(10)

SET @PAT = '%[^'+ CHAR(13) + ']' + CHAR(10) + '%'

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
('AAA')
,('BBB' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'BBB')
,('CCC' + CHAR(10) + 'CCC')

SELECT * FROM @T AS t
WHERE PATINDEX(@PAT, S) > 0
```

Comment: This might be a noobie question, but what's the purpose of  `AAA` `BBB` and `CCC`?

Comment: @user3394493 Just demo code, so you can tell which row gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  example.ID
, example.DESCRIPTION
FROM MyTable
WHERE example.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'%'         --contains CRLF 
  AND (example.DESCRIPTION LIKE CHAR(10)+'%'                     --AND (starts with LF
    OR example.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%[^'+CHAR(13)+']'+CHAR(10)+'%') --     OR contains [^CR]LF)
```